# SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I updated **webpack** version from 4.0.0 to 5.52.1 and after compiled with '**bin/webpack**' the result is **webpack 5.52.1 compiled successfully** 
But, I have the error message like the following

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(https?://)?((([a-zd]([a-zd-]*[a-zd])*).)+[a-z]{2,}|((d{1,3}.){3}d{1,3}))(:d+)?(/[-a-zd%_.~+]*)*(?[&a-zd%_.~+=-]*)?(#[-a-zd_]*)?$/: Invalid group
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at /node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:410:24
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:16)
    at JavascriptParser.evaluateExpression (/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:3150:25)
    at JavascriptParser.getRenameIdentifier (/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1366:23)
    at JavascriptParser.walkVariableDeclaration (/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:2058:31)
    at JavascriptParser.walkStatement (/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1566:10)
    at JavascriptParser.walkStatements (/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1427:9)
    at /node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:1601:9
    at JavascriptParser.inBlockScope (/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js:3048:3)
.
.
.
webpack 5.52.1 compiled successfully
```

I have no idea about this because I can compile with webpack 4.0.0 without error message but after migrated to webpack 5.52.1 I got the error at **new RegExp** at **/node_modules/webpack/lib/javascript/JavascriptParser.js** and there is no **/^(https?://)?(((a-zd*).)+[a-z]{2,}|((d{1,3}.){3}d{1,3}))(:d+)?(/[-a-zd%_.~+]*)*(?[&a-zd%_.~+=-]*)?(#[-a-zd_]*)?$/** in my script can anyone advise how can I find the root cause and fix this 
**Resources:**
**rails**: 6.1.4 
**webpacker**: 6.0.0.rc.2 
**webpack**: 5.52.1 
**webpack-cli**: 4.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix it with the following steps

1. change from **webpacker** to **shakapacker**
2. update the syntax from **const componentRequireContext =
   require.context("components", true);**
   to
   **const
   componentRequireContext = require.context( "components", true,
   /^(https?://)?(((a-z\d*).)+[a-z]{2,}|((\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}))(:\d+)?(/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*(?:[&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?(#[-a-z\d_]*)?$/
   );**

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a colon after `(?` and lost backslashes, double them inside constructor:

```js
new RegExp('^(https?://)?((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))(:\\d+)?(/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*(?:[&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?(#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$')
```

Else use regex literal:

```js
/^(https?:\/\/)?((([a-z\d]([a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])*)\.)+[a-z]{2,}|((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))(:\d+)?(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*(?:[&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?(#[-a-z\d_]*)?$/
```

Comment: Now, I can fix it with the following steps 
1). change from "webpacker" to "shakapacker"
2). update the syntax from "const componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);" to "const componentRequireContext = require.context(
  "components",
  true,
  /^(https?:\/\/)?((([a-z\d]([a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])*)\.)+[a-z]{2,}|((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))(:\d+)?(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*(?:[&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?(#[-a-z\d_]*)?$/
);"

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slashes in the regex by pretending backslahes to them. Additionally, you have a redundant `?` at the beginning of the penultimate group:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?((([a-zd]([a-zd-]*[a-zd])*).)+[a-z]{2,}|((d{1,3}.){3}d{1,3}))(:d+)?(\/[-a-zd%_.~+]*)*([&a-zd%_.~+=-]*)?(#[-a-zd_]*)?$
```